# Authenticated and None Authenticated Verification Path

Tags: python, web, fastapi, web-frameworks, pyjwt

So using fastapi PyJWT which works well, I'm struggling to making this work

```py
user_dep = Annotated[Dict,Depends(api.get_current_user)]
@app.get('/')
async def home(request: Request,user:user_dep=Optional[models.AuthorizedUser]):
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        return RedirectResponse(url='/dashboard/')
    return templates.TemplateResponse('home.html',context={'request':request})
```

Intended functionality: If the user was already logged it, they will automatically get redirected to the intended page I want

Running this exact piece of code and when I guess the `/` path, it returns 401 Unauthorized which is not what I currently what for this one.

```py
async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str,Depends(oauth2_bearer)]):
       try:
              payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
              username: str = payload.get('username')
              user_id: int = payload.get('id')
              rank: str = payload.get('rank')
              division: str = payload.get('division')
              if username is None or user_id is None:
                     return None
                     #raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Could not validate user")
              return {'username': username, 'id': user_id, 'rank': rank, 'division':division}
       except PyJWTError:
              return None
              #raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail="Could not validate credentials")
```

Is there a possibility I am missing some steps, or anything?

I've tried everything, even sometimes, removing doing this:

`=

````py
@app.get('/')
async def home(request: Request,user:user_dep=None):
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        return RedirectResponse(url='/dashboard/')
    return templates.TemplateResponse('home.html',context={'request':request})```

```py
@app.get('/')
async def home(request: Request):
        user = await user_dep()
    print(user)
    if user is not None:
        return RedirectResponse(url='/dashboard/')
    return templates.TemplateResponse('home.html',context={'request':request})
````

Nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OAuth2PasswordBearer` will (by default) generate a 401 error when an `Authorization` header is not present, so your dependency code never actually runs (so you can't return `None`).

To change the behavior you can supply the parameter `auto_error` when creating your `OAuth2PasswordBearer` instance.

> By default, if no HTTP Auhtorization header is provided, required for OAuth2 authentication, it will automatically cancel the request and send the client an error.
>
> If `auto_error` is set to `False`, when the HTTP Authorization header is not available, instead of erroring out, the dependency result will be `None`.
>
> This is useful when you want to have optional authentication.
>
> It is also useful when you want to have authentication that can be provided in one of multiple optional ways (for example, with OAuth2 or in a cookie).

You then check if `token` is `None` before attempting to decode it in your authentication function.

However, be aware that this will also make all other endpoints available if no token is present, just without user information. A solution to this is to define two `get_current_user` functions, one `get_current_user` and one `get_optional_user`, which in turn either can depend on two differently configured instances of `OAuth2PasswordBearer`, or you can handle the `None` case for the token in your `get_current_user` function and raise a 401 if the token isn't present yourself.